# sudo apt-get update error: Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, update-manager

I recently tried to install npm and nodejs and got some errors and was suggested to run sudo apt-get update.

After running sudo apt-get update I get the following error:

```
 Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/trusty/Release  Unable to find expected entry 'universe/binary-amd64/Packages' in Release file (Wrong sources.list entry or malformed file)

 E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

The output of `cat /etc/apt/sources.list` is :

`deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu trusty main universe restricted multiverse`

Answer (score 0):

This is because most of your PPA are outdated or doesn't exist anymore.

Look at your `/etc/sources.list` (or the files in `/etc/sources.list.d`) and remove or fix those lines that cause the error.

Also have a look at this answer [by fossfreedom](https://askubuntu.com/questions/65911/how-can-i-fix-a-404-error-using-a-ppa) for a good and detailed explanation and it will help you.

Comment: Tried this and it didn't work. It told me no ppas to be removed

Comment: Try another archive mirror. You can change the server location in `System Settings, Software&Updates, Download from:`. Maybe the file on the server you currently use is broken. The problem might also go away then after a few hours or days if that was the case.